# How do I test New Relic (in Python) during local development?

Tags: python, testing, newrelic, metrics

I'm interested in using the New Relic Python agent's concept of a [data source](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/customization-extension/python-custom-metrics-api#register_data_source) to capture a custom metric via polling. The documentation is clear enough that I *think* I understand how to set that up; but (understandly) I'd like to verify my code locally before deploying it.

What I'm not seeing from New Relic's docs is a way to test code that collects custom metrics locally, without actually sending data to New Relic's servers. I see that there's a [developer_mode](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-configuration#developer_mode) configuration setting; but it *seems* like that just verifies that nothing breaks code-wise (not that my custom metrics actually *work*). I tried enabling that in tandem with the [log_file](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-configuration#log_file) setting in the hope that it would produce some logs that would show me what New Relic will do once I deploy my changes; but that didn't seem to produce any logs.

How is this generally handled? Do most teams using New Relic just have a dev application (that they pay for) and report stats to that during local dev? Do they *not* test their New Relic stuff locally?